# How can i get the name of a variable name of a parameter in Java

Tags: java, parameters

I am passing an object as a parameter to a method. 
i'd like to know the name of that object-- 
that specific reference variable i've been using to pass the object to the method. 
is there a way to find out about this?

Or, generally, is there a way to find out about the name of variable used by the 
calling method to pass that value to the method invoked ? thanks in advance.

**Note**-- regarding the first Q above: i am aware that an object can have 
many handles pointing to it. this is rather a question of whether the 
parameter names are getting "special attention" of some sort in the method, or aren't of any concern once they pass the value.

Comment: What if the parameter being passed is not a variable but rather an expression?

Comment: good point. then maybe it could return a null value-- if there is some method telling me that name.

Comment: why would you want to do that? If performance is not very important you could maintain a `Map<Integer, String>` where key is the index of the parameter and value the _name_ of it. To handle nested method calls you would have to maintain a `Stack<Map<Integer, String>>`. It's possible, but pure overkill. Probably better solutions to the problem you are facing. Can you tell us more about that?

Comment: @jlordo: pls read my comment on Jan Dvorak's answer below.

Comment: doesn't exactly answer the question why you want to access variable _names_. After all, the concept of variables is to _store_ the data, not to be the data.

Comment: @jlordo: i'm convinced that it's not been worth for Java to implement this in the language. as for your Q, see Jan Dvorak's code. i`m trying to avoid that string parameter in the call.

Comment: I get how you're trying to solve your problem. My question to you is, *why* do you need to know the _name_ of the parameter within a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is more than the information placed on the stack by Java.  The JVM has no reason to record the name of a variable when it takes the handle held by that variable and puts it into the stack to call a method.  In fact, there's usually no real reason to preserve that name past compilation.  If you can give more information about why you'd want to do such a thing you'll probably get more reasonable responses.

If what you wanted were possible, it would be via a [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html), but looking at the API, there's nothing like what you're asking for.

Comment: any direct references on what exactly goes into a stack when you invoke a Java method ? i know generally what type of things are pushed into a stack on a function call. thanks for the response.

Comment: exactly what goes into the stack would probably be JVM dependent.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html looks cool. will look into it sometime. 

should be able to trace whats kept on a method call by setting it whichever the way ir needs be.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one reason this cannot work. Most importantly:

The argument to a function needs not be a variable. You could request the textual representation of the expression, but that needs a lot of unused data being stored with the program. Not even variable names are being stored with the program. The only variable names that are preserved by compilation are static and instance fields and methods. Even then, there's no way (short of trying to decompile the caller) to access the calling expression.

If you need a function to have this kind of data, you need to supply it as a separate argument:

```
doLog(foo, "foo");
doLog(new Foo(), "new Foo()");
/*or*/ doLog(new Foo(), null);
```

Comment: thats what ive been doing. this is a method declared in an interface and it adds another parameter just for this to every class implementing it.